# collect 1st element in an array using classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a 2-D array in classic asp, 
my aim is to find 1st element in that array and save it in a variable. after that remaining elements(except the first element) are saved in same array.

Example: 
if "`aryReturn`" is an array like.

```
aryReturn(0,0) = 1001
aryReturn(1,0) = 1002
aryReturn(2,0) = 1003 
aryReturn(3,0) = 1004
aryReturn(4,0) = 1005
aryReturn(5,0) = 1006
```

Now I want to find the 1st element(`aryReturn(0,0)= 1001`) in `Dim intValue`.

```
intValue = 1001
```

then after that, it sholud return the array with remaining elements.
aryReturn =

```
aryReturn(0,0) = 1002
aryReturn(1,0) = 1003
aryReturn(2,0) = 1004 
aryReturn(3,0) = 1005
aryReturn(4,0) = 1006
```

Please help me... thanks in adv.

Comment: Hi Petrioli, may i know what is the reason to not acceptable my post.

Comment: Does it need to be a 2-dimensional array? Normally you could use Redim preserve.. but this can only be used for the last dimension of a dynamic array

Answer (score 0):

I think I've answered your question. The code below might help you.

```
dim aryReturn(5,0)
aryReturn(0,0) = 1001
aryReturn(1,0) = 1002
aryReturn(2,0) = 1003 
aryReturn(3,0) = 1004
aryReturn(4,0) = 1005
aryReturn(5,0) = 1006
var1=aryReturn(0,0)
  for i=0 to ubound(aryReturn)-1
     aryReturn(i,0)=aryReturn(i+1,0)
  response.Write(aryReturn(i,0)&"<br>")
  next
```