# Remove 1st element in the classic asp array

Tags: asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [collect 1st element in an array using classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672926/collect-1st-element-in-an-array-using-classic-asp)

I have a 2-D array in classic asp, 
my aim is to find 1st element in that array and save it in a variable. after that remaining elements(except the first element) are saved in same array.

Example: 
if "`aryReturn`" is an array like.

```
aryReturn(0,0) = 1001
aryReturn(1,0) = 1002
aryReturn(2,0) = 1003 
aryReturn(3,0) = 1004
aryReturn(4,0) = 1005
aryReturn(5,0) = 1006
```

Now I want to find the 1st element(`aryReturn(0,0)= 1001`) in `Dim intValue`.

```
intValue = 1001
```

then after that, it sholud return the array with remaining elements.
aryReturn =

```
aryReturn(0,0) = 1002
aryReturn(1,0) = 1003
aryReturn(2,0) = 1004 
aryReturn(3,0) = 1005
aryReturn(4,0) = 1006
```

Please help me... thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

contents.remove("aryReturn")(0,0)

Comment: Too short an answer to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I studied a lot of pages to this topic. All pages I found recomments the rebuild of the existing array without the element which you want to remove. [This](http://www.naterice.com/articles/67)
page is quite easy to read. In case you are not satisfet try the keywords **vbscript remove array item** for other pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any such direct function. You can use my small code. Just copy and paste. I think you can use it

```
dim aryReturn(5,0)
aryReturn(0,0) = 1001
aryReturn(1,0) = 1002
aryReturn(2,0) = 1003 
aryReturn(3,0) = 1004
aryReturn(4,0) = 1005
aryReturn(5,0) = 1006
var1=aryReturn(0,0)
  for i=0 to ubound(aryReturn)-1
     aryReturn(i,0)=aryReturn(i+1,0)
  response.Write(aryReturn(i,0)&"<br>")
  next
```